# Storing remote notifications locally

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to store all pushed notifications in Core Data and to display them to the user. In fact I already did implement `didReceiveRemoteNotification:` and it's working like it should:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

    Notification *notify = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Notification" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    notify.timeStamp = [NSDate date];
    notify.alert = [[userInfo valueForKeyPath:@"aps"] valueForKeyPath:@"alert"];

    NSError *error;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't save to persistant store.");
    }
}
```

But when I put this code inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in some condition statement:

```
if (launchOptions != nil)
    {
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
        if (dictionary != nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Launched from push notification: %@", dictionary);

            Notification *notify = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Notification" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
            notify.timeStamp = [NSDate date];
            notify.alert = [[dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"aps"] valueForKeyPath:@"alert"];

            NSError *error;
            if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Couldn't save to persistant store.");
            }
        }
    }
```

I get nothing... I've tried creating `UIAlertView` and it is showing proper aler from the aps but when I try saving to persistant store and diplay it in MasterViewController nothing happens.

Maybe anyone know why? Is it because of some sort of lifecycle issues which I'm interrupting?

## Edit

I've tried putting `UIAlertView` when the saving is successful  inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and it is showing so I guess everything is saved correctly but the `NSFetchedResultController` doesn't show those notifications... Why?

Answer (score 2):

You can save notification when app is in running state only.**If app in background or closed,push receives but you can't access and save the payload information because none of the delegate method will execute during this time**.You can implement this with the help of server side only and they can save the pushed notifications.Pass this notification list using an api call.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a copy of the notification instead of the original notification. Data could be removed and you have an empty reference.

Answer (score 0):

In fact there was no problem with saving but with displaying stored data. My solution was cache in `NSFetchedResultsController`.